# Generic Object Cache

Tags: c#, linq, caching

I am working on a project where I plan on using Redis as persistent data storage, however the task at hand, I am working on a generic Object cache. and as a huge fan of LINQ I have started designing a cache which does support this.

```
    public ConcurrentBag<Object> Cache = new ConcurrentBag<object>();

    public List<T> FindBy<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        var tmp = new List<T>();

        foreach (var i in Cache)
        {
            try
            {
                T obj = i as T;

                if (obj != null)
                    tmp.Add(obj);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        return tmp.Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
```

I am afraid that when the object cache grows large it will become inefficient. (I estimate 500k-1m objects)

I was hoping that it would be possible to use something like this

```
    public ConcurrentBag<Object> Cache = new ConcurrentBag<object>();

    public List<T> FindBy<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        return Cache.Where<T>(predicate).ToList();
    }
```

Hopefully I am not all off-track here? Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Can you be more specific at what exactly your problem is? You can use LINQ on a `ConcurrentBag` and you can take a snapshot by prepending a `ToList()`.

Comment: Hi Theodoros, well the bag is just a list of Objects all mixed together, so in example. I have added a few hundred objects of one type and a few hundred objects of another, now i want to skip the step of having to iterate through each type then predicate the list. as i show in my first example.

Comment: You might want to use [the existing generic object cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache(v=vs.110).aspx) built in to .NET as a base for your custom cache. That way you get some cache features for free like cache expirations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you estimate a lot of items in the cache and the operations on the cache will be type specific, you could use multiple bags wrapped into a dictionary. That would speed up finding the subset of the cache of type of interest and would be ideal if the cache contained many minimal subsets of different types.

```
readonly IDictionary<Type, ConcurrentBag<object>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentBag<object>>();

public List<T> FindBy<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
{
    // Check if items of type {T} exist in the cache.
    ConcurrentBag<object> bag;
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(typeof (T), out bag))
    {
        // Cast, apply predicate and return.
        return bag.Cast<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
    // Return an empty list.
    return new List<T>();
}
```

Of course now you also need to handle adding items properly to the cache to ensure that different types will be put into their corresponding bags.

Answer (score 3):

Hash your genric type and save list of specific type..
Something like:

```
Dictionary<Type,List<T>>
```

Then get value by type key and query as you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to both [Discosultan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466456/discosultan) and [user1190916](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190916/user1190916) Whom both pointed me in the right direction in what I needed to get a CRUD cached-object repository with full LINQ support using Redis for persistent storage (Client [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis)), this is what I have managed to conjure up thus far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using ServiceStack.Redis;

namespace RedisTestRepo
{
    class Program
    {
        //public static DataRepository Db;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Repo r = new Repo();

            // We do not touch sequence, by running example we can see that sequence will give Users new unique Id.

            // Empty data store.
            Console.WriteLine("Our User Data store should be empty.");
            Console.WriteLine("Users In \"Database\" : {0}\n", r.All<User>().Count);

            // Add imaginary users.
            Console.WriteLine("Adding 100 imaginairy users.");
            for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
                r.Create<User>(new User { Id = r.Next<User>(), Name = "Joachim Nordvik" });

            // We should have 100 users in data store.
            Console.WriteLine("Users In \"Database\" : {0}\n", r.All<User>().Count);

            // Lets print 10 users from data store.
            Console.WriteLine("Order by Id, Take (10) and print users.");
            foreach (var u in r.All<User>().OrderBy(z => z.Id).Take(10))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}, Name: {1}", u.Id, u.Name);

                // Lets update an entity.
                u.Name = "My new Name";
                r.Update<User>(x=>x.Id == u.Id, u);
            }


            // Lets print 20 users from data store, we already edited 10 users.
            Console.WriteLine("\nOrder by Id, Take (20) and print users, we previously edited the users that we printed lets see if it worked.");
            foreach (var u in r.All<User>().OrderBy(z => z.Id).Take(20))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}, Name: {1}", u.Id, u.Name);
            }

            // Clean up data store.
            Console.WriteLine("\nCleaning up Data Store.\n");
            foreach (var u in r.All<User>())
                r.Delete<User>(u);

            // Confirm that we no longer have any users.
            Console.WriteLine("Confirm that we no longer have User entities in Data Store.");
            Console.WriteLine("Users In \"Database\" : {0}\n\n", r.All<User>().Count);

            Console.WriteLine("Hit return to exit!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Repo
    {
        private static readonly PooledRedisClientManager m = new PooledRedisClientManager();

        public Repo()
        {
            // Spool Redis Database into our object cache.
            LoadIntoCache<User>();
        }

        readonly IDictionary<Type, List<object>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, List<object>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Load {T} into object cache from Data Store.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">class</typeparam>
        private void LoadIntoCache<T>() where T : class
        {
            _cache[typeof(T)] = GetAll<T>().Cast<object>().ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add single {T} into cache and Data Store.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">class</typeparam>
        /// <param name="entity">class object</param>
        public void Create<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            List<object> list;
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
            {
                list = new List<object>();
            }
            list.Add(entity);
            _cache[typeof(T)] = list;
            Store<T>(entity);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete single {T} from cache and Data Store.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">class</typeparam>
        /// <param name="entity">class object</param>
        public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            List<object> list;
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
            {
                list.Remove(entity);
                _cache[typeof(T)] = list;

                RedisDelete<T>(entity);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to update or Add entity to object cache and Data Store.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">class</typeparam>
        /// <param name="predicate">linq expression</param>
        /// <param name="entity">entity</param>
        public void Update<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate, T entity) where T : class
        {
            List<object> list;
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
            {
                // Look for old entity.
                var e = list.Cast<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();

                if(e != null)
                {
                    list.Remove(e);
                }

                // Regardless if object existed or not we add it to our Cache / Data Store.
                list.Add(entity);
                _cache[typeof(T)] = list;
                Store<T>(entity);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find List<T>(predicate) in cache.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">class</typeparam>
        /// <param name="predicate">linq statement</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<T> FindBy<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
        {
            List<object> list;
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
            {
                return list.Cast<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
            }
            return new List<T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find All {T}
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <returns>List<T></returns>
        public List<T> All<T>() where T : class
        {
            return GetAll<T>().ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find Single {T} in object cache.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">class</typeparam>
        /// <param name="predicate">linq statement</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T Read<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
        {
            List<object> list;
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list))
            {
                return list.Cast<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public long Next<T>() where T : class
        {
            long id = 1;

            using (var ctx = m.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    id =  ctx.As<T>().GetNextSequence();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // Add exception handler.
                }
            }


            return id;
        }

        private void RedisDelete<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            using (var ctx = m.GetClient())
                ctx.As<T>().Delete(entity);
        }

        private T Find<T>(long id) where T : class
        {
            using (var ctx = m.GetClient())
                return ctx.As<T>().GetById(id);
        }

        private IList<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
        {
            using(var ctx = m.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    return ctx.As<T>().GetAll();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return new List<T>();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Store<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            using (var ctx = m.GetClient())
                ctx.Store<T>(entity);
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```